# Hide Azure Boards from the dropbox in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

We use a single ADO Project for all our systems. In this project we have multiple ADO Teams created, each with their own Board.

In the Area Path of each team we applied permissions in a way that only the actual dev-team may have access to that area path. The permissions are working, since users without the permissions are not allowed to view or create work items.

However, our problem is that all users seem to be able to see all boards.

Since we have dozens of boards the dropdown is becoming too long, and we would like to hide boards that some teams or some users are not supposed to work with.

In short: teams should see only the boards they are assigned with.

Is it possible to hide a board using permissions, or other configuration?

**UPDATE:** I created [this feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Hide-Azure-Boards-from-the-dropbox-in-Az/1348142) for this functionality.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid it is impossible and there is no other configuration that can achieve this.

There is user voice having been submitted to Microsoft development team regarding this issue. Check [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/restrict-users-from-accessing-other-team/855653?space=21&q=hide%20team%20boards%20from%20dropdown%20list).  You can vote it it up. Or [create a new user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) of your own.

Comment: Created a user voice, let us see the response: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Hide-Azure-Boards-from-the-dropbox-in-Az/1348142